# Calculating a surface integral using change of coordinates.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

I need to use
 $u=x+y,\ v=x^2+y^2$
to find $I=\int_D x+y\ dxdy$ where $D=\{ (x,y)\ :\ x^2+y^2=1, y\geq 0\}$.

I think the region for the $u-v$ plane is the rectangle $\{(u,v)\ :\ -1\leq u\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\leq v\leq 1\}$ but i'm having trouble finding the jacobian.

When finding the jacobian I used that $\frac{\partial y,x}{\partial u,v} =1/\frac{\partial u,v}{\partial x,y} $ and found that it's $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2v-u^2}}$ though I'm having trouble computing the integral still when i put into the change of coordinate formula. And for the region I used a sketch.

Comment: Why don't you use polar change ? Because you're set is the half upper circle of radius 1. I

Comment: The question specifies this coordinate change

Comment: Ok I'm writting an answer, I post it when you will show us what you have tried.

Comment: First try your by yourself and show us what you have done, this site is not here to do your homework...

Comment: i have tried it, I'm stuck....

Comment: @userbignumber What we ask you is just to write what you have done, so people that help you know that you have tried something.

Comment: I hope the edit helps

Comment: I think that covers my approach, when I use my Jacobian I get an integral which i can't seem to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining

$$ f :(x,y) \to (x+y,x^2+y^2)$$

$$ \nabla f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
2x & 2y 
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$J_f(x,y)=(1-2y)-(1-2x)=2(x-y) $$

So $f$ is a bijection from $D$ to $D'=[-1,\sqrt2]\times\{1\}- \{ x(u,v)=y (u,v)\}$

So once you have the expression of 
$$  x(u,v) \\
y(u,v) $$

Put in $J_f$,invert it and then :

Your integral is :

$$ I=\int_{D'}(x(u,v)+y(u,v))|J_f^{-1}(u,v)|dudv $$

Comment: How did you find that $0\leq u\leq 1/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I mod it. Trace a up-hemisphere, and see the value of when $x+y$ is maximum on the circle (it is for $x=\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta)=y=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$

Comment: thanks for the help